# SAML2 - Login user from IdP initiated request

Tags: sustainsys-saml2

I'm trying to figure out **how to login user** in standard Web Forms application and Owin enabled Web Forms application **using IdP initiated request** and Sustainsys SAML2 library.

I have IdP on Azure, I can send request and Azure can send POST with SAMLResponse to my ACS endpoint.

But I don't know ho to login user using this token. There is no example in Sustainsys documentation.

```
    var spOptions = new SPOptions
    {
        EntityId = new EntityId("https://localhost:44317/Saml2"),
        ReturnUrl = new Uri("https://localhost:44317/Saml2/Acs")
    };
```

On Azure IdP
Basic SAML Configuration

```
Identifier (Entity ID): https://localhost:44317/Saml2
Reply URL (Assertion Consumer Service URL): https://localhost:44317/Saml2/Acs
```

IdP works fine, I can see POST with token to my site. But I thought that there is some autologin feature. But seems that I was wrong.

So my questions are:

- Where should I set Return url to get response? Is ACS endpoind correct?
- How to process token and login user using handlers and Owin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The ACS Endpoint is correct.
- The `SPOptions.ReturnUrl` should be set to a location in your application where you want the user to end up *after* the authentication is complete.

You also need to set the `AllowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse` flag on the Idp to allow Idp initiated login.